# Using set to change property value in a constructor, C#

Tags: c#, constructor, object-create

The program I wrote works, and prints fine. It creates two objects fine. One object is to be created using the no-arg default constructor, and the other is to be created from the non-default constructor. The only difference is I am supposed to use the set keyword for Author to create a default value. So that when I go to create the object with the wrong author name it will change it using the set keyword.

When I enter in the wrong value for Book1.Author for the non-default constructor, it changes both Author names in both objects. How do I only allow it to change the author name in my Book1 object?

```
using System;
namespace Book
{
    public class Book
    {
        private string _Author;
        private string _Title;
        private string _Keywords;
        private string _publicationDate;
        private string _ISBN;

        public Book()
        {
            Author = "";
        }

        public Book(string title, string author, string publicationDate, string keywords, string isbn)
        {
            Title = title;
            Author = author;
            Keywords = keywords;
            PublicationDate = publicationDate;
            ISBN = isbn;
        }
        public string Title { get => _Title; set => _Title = value; }
        public string Author { get => _Author; set => _Author = "Mary Delamater and Joel Murach, "; }
        public string Keywords { get => _Keywords; set => _Keywords = value; }
        public string PublicationDate { get => _publicationDate; set => _publicationDate = value; }
        public string ISBN { get => _ISBN; set => _ISBN = value; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Title + Author + PublicationDate + "Keywords: " + Keywords + "ISBN " + ISBN;
    
        
        }

        
    

    }
}
```

```
using System;

namespace Book
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Book Book1 = new Book("murach's ASP.NET Core MVC, ", "Mary Delamater and Joel Murach, ", "January 2020, ", "C#, Programming, MVC, ASP.NET, Core, Beginner", "978-1-943872-49-7");
            Console.WriteLine(Book1.ToString());
            Book Book2 = new Book();
            Book2.Title = "C# In Depth, ";
            Book2.Author = "John Skeet, ";
            Book2.PublicationDate = "March 23, 2019, ";
            Book2.Keywords = "C#, InDepth";
            Book2.ISBN = "9781617294532";
            Console.WriteLine(Book2.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the sample what can be going wrong?

Comment: "When I enter in the wrong value for Book1.Author .... it changes both Author names in both objects. " what objects are you talking about?

Comment: `set => _Author = "Mary Delamater and Joel Murach, ";` should be `set => _Author = value;`, surely? And you'd assign the intended string *from the specific place*? The setter isn't the default; it is what happens *any time you assign any value to the property*, and right now, what happens is you ignore the value being assigned, and change the field to a fixed value

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the program flow is wrong. In your constructor when you call your properties to set value, the program flow will run the `set` part which you hardcoded to a string. Now if you try to save your value via this property by an object or in a constructor it will always set to the hardcoded value irrespective of what you want. To store a custom value, you have to use `set=>value` and to apply your business constraint, you can write logical conditions inside your property which is why properties are used for to achieve encapsulation.

Something like this:

```
public string Author{
  get{
    return _Author;
  }
  set{
    if()//your condition to validate if author is wrong
      _Author = ""; //your expected correct author name
    else
      _Author = value
  }
}
```